# How to do this ODE??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE problem of:

$(x^2+y^2-5) dx = (y+xy)dy, y(0)=1$.

I write this in the exact form : $(x^2+y^2-5)/(1+x)^3 dx -y/(1+x)^2 dy = 0$ then, $f(x,y) = -y^2/(2(1+x)^2) +h(x)$ where $h^\prime(x) = (x^2-5)/(1+x)^3$. But then I'm stuck at trying to integrate and get $h(x)$. Any advice?

Comment: What about partial fractions decomposition?

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: I meant representing $\frac{x^2-5}{(1+x)^3}$ in the form $$\frac{A}{1+x} + \frac{B}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{C}{(1+x)^3} $$ with $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$. One usually equates the two expressions and solves a linear system in the unknowns $A$, $B$ and $C$, but in this case, the easiest way to find these constants is to put $x = t-1$ and expand $\frac{x^2-5}{(1+x)^3} = \frac{(t-1)^2-5}{t^3}$ in powers of $t$. See the answer by @David below.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac{x^2-5}{(1+x)^3}\,dx=\int\frac{(1+x)^2-2(1+x)-4}{(1+x)^3}\,dx=\cdots\ ?$$

Comment: wait a minute...! This is just partial fractions in disguise :)

Comment: @BennettGardiner Indeed it is!  Partial fractions are exceptionally simple when the denominator of the required function is just a power of a single linear factor.

Comment: I see that, now! A very cool little trick that I'll now never forget, thanks!